# How to handle Windows domain users that are not connected to the domain network for long periods of time?

Tags: active-directory, login, timeout

I have a number of users with Windows laptops on a Windows domain that are often not able to connect to the domain network to log in.   I initially set up their machine, log them in, set up their profile and it works fine for a while - 2 weeks or so I believe.

However, unless they are able to plug in to the network to reach the domain controller, they eventually are unable to log in to their machine.

I like this, but for certain specific users it would be nice to allow them to continue to log in either for a much longer time frame or indefinitely.

I know I can create a local user on the computer for the user, but are there any other options?    For example, what if I create a [restricted group to make the user a local admin](http://www.frickelsoft.net/blog/?p=13) in active directory - would that work and prevent this timeout period?

Or, possibly I can do something on the local machine?   Maybe there is a way to specify the timeout for the user or machine in AD?

Comment: Why can't they logon? Usually if a user's credentials are cached, you don't have to worry about anything. Do the user's get any errors, or anything showing up in the event log? Might check to see if you have some password experation policy setup on the laptops.

Comment: It says something to the effect of 'can not contact the domain server'.  I have also seen a message about domain trust being invalid.   Sorry for the vague messages, I will clarify next time I see one.  I find that cached credentials last at least a week, maybe two, but after some time they become invalid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what's happening is that the machine password is expiring. Check out this link:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc781050%28WS.10%29.aspx

Comment: I like this answer, I just need to do some testing to confirm.

Comment: @ScottSzretter Don't keep us in suspense!